# Largest Prime Factor (return)

Tags: java

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(prime(prime(600851475143L));

    }

    public static long prime(long x) {
        long d = 0;

        for (long s = x; s > 0; s--) {
            if (x % s == 0)
                d = s;

            for (long sp = s; sp > 0; sp--) {
                while (sp != 1) {
                    if (s % sp == 0) {
                        d = sp;
                    }


                }
                if (d == s) {
                    return d;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The prime()method keep asking me for a return,which I already wrote in the code.Is there anything I didn't do right?Thank you. NEED MORE TEXTsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: prime() has one return statement, for some particular tests. You need a return statement for all possibilities, not just that one test.

Comment: There's so much wrong here though - perhaps try something more basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have placed the return statement inside an if. If d!=s your method is not returning something.

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is under an `if` condition. Add a `return` before the closing braces of your method. Perhaps put a `break` inside your `if` condition and add `return d` before closing braces.